# Facebook PHP SDK getting likes count

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I've a facebook app which posts in the user wall. In the post there is a link (to my app) and in the liked page there is a [like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Now I'm making a script that will run once per hour (set from the crontab). In that script I need to get two different likes count:

1. Likes in the message posted in the wall.
2. Likes done in my app (with the button).

**For the first one I've made this code:**

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
              'method' => 'fql.query',
              'query' => 'SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id="'.$idPost.'"'
          ));
$likesWall = count($result);
```

This code was working, but suddenly it is not. It throws this exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 190:
>   Error validating access token: The
>   session is invalid because the user
>   logged out. thrown in C:\(...)\facebook\base_facebook.php
>   on line 656

**For the second likes count**

I really don't know how I have to do it. I've tried:

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
              'method' => 'links.getStats',
              'urls' => $canvasPage."somePage.php?id=".$id
          ));
```

But this throws:

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException:
>   60: SSL certificate problem, verify
>   that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed thrown in
>   C:\(...)\facebook\base_facebook.php
>   on line 759

And then this was given to me: [http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=**http://apps.facebook.com/appName/somePage.php?id=68**&metadata=1](http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=%2a%2ahttp://apps.facebook.com/appName/somePage.php?id=68%2a%2a&metadata=1) where the bold part is the url in the like button I created. When I put it in the browser it returns me a JSON with some information (including the likes count) but I don't know how to use it in my script.

**More information:**

Here is the code to define facebook object:

```
include_once 'facebook/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appId,
    'secret' => $secret
  ));
```

I'm using the latest version the SDK (v3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

I made it this way:

```
function get_content($url){
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    //return $header;
    return $content;
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appId,
    'secret' => $secret
));

$accessToken = get_content("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=".$appId."&client_secret=".$secret);
$accessToken = substr($accessToken, strpos($accessToken, "=") + 1);

$fqlResult = get_content("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+user_id+FROM+like+WHERE+post_id%3D\"".$idPost."\"&format=json&access_token=".$accessToken);
$fqlResult = json_decode($fqlResult);
$countLikesWall = count($fqlResult);

$fqlResult = get_content("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+like_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D\"http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F**MyAppsName**%2F**somePage**.php%3Fid%3D".$id."\"&format=json&access_token=".$accessToken);
$fqlResult = json_decode($fqlResult);

$countLikesUrl = $fqlResult[0]->like_count;
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: function get_content($url){ that part, surely you call the function somehow, and what do you put as the $url?

Comment: You have to put any of the URLs of the facebook API. In the code it is shown how. After creating $facebook I use get_content three times.

Comment: why do you still load the Facebook class?

Comment: @Andrei I made that code a long time ago, but it seems not to be use. I suppose with all the refactoring I forgot to removing the line.

Answer (score 0):

You should add that the App needs "read_stream" permission from the user. If you don't have that permission the query will return an empty array like this "[ ]".

Comment: Will do, thanks! I think this should be a comment in the answer, not an other answer.